# Smooth interpolating heatmap from arrays (but non-grid data) in python or gnuplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, gnuplot, interpolation, heatmap

I am looking for a way to plot a heat-map in python from data x,y,C, where C is there color of a given coordinate (x,y). Most of the methods are transforming x,y via mesh-grid, however it would be a discontinuous mesh-grid.

Example Data:

## x    y     C

3.5 0.05    2
3.5 0.00    2
3.5 -0.05   0
3.5 -0.10   0

My data represents a phase structure, which means that there are large regions of the same color, and more-or-less well defined lines are separating the regions. I would like to have smooth coloured regions without holes.

Comment: [`tricontourf`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html) also accepts x and y arrays without structure as input. [Examples](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/tricontour_demo.html)

Comment: Also [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html) example assumes fully unstructured x-y coordinates.